Play DRM Content in Horizon Session
this is pretty straightforward. the DRM content playback implementation in browsers as it presently stands, interferes with the horizon session being able to transmit the content over the horizon session to the client station.
i do believe this remains true no matter the remoting protocol used. (RDP, parallels, etc) the way it usually manifests is you get audio and nothing but a black screen for the video.
more and more websites are starting to use DRM controlled content, so all of it gets lost on our VDI setup, which is what basically runs our entire company. using MMR would also not solve the issue. so how are admins out there dealing with it?
